# amazon aws, ec2 not working DNS address

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have a micro instance of a Ubuntu virtual server on my EC2. When I go to the terminal and ping Google is working, but when I go to the DNS address for my site, it doesn't work.

```
Public DNS: ec2-107-20-20-19.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

This are my security group settings:
[image]

What do I need to access the site?

Comment: What do you mean by "access"?  SSH?  The web server?

Comment: @cjc hi thanks to see the site is live on my browser,

Comment: so why the down vote?

Comment: I didn't do it.  Likely it was the lack of information/specificity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stock Ubuntu images don't come with much installed. If you haven't installed a web server (Apache, nginx, etc.), nothing's going to respond when you visit the site in a browser.

If you have installed a web server, make sure it's running, and that you haven't installed some sort of software firewall that's blocking port 80.

Comment: oh of course!, I haven't installed any web server :p

Comment: That'll do it. Heh.

Comment: MaKo: Make sure to mark this as the answer when you get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

The ping command is actually blocked by the firewall. It's not UDP or TCP protocol either, you need to add a rule to allow ICMP for your security group. Just enable all the rules for ICMP on all hosts.

That being said. It's not a good practice to enable ping as it opens your servers to attacks pretty easily. If you're just trying to see if the server is online you can connect to the server use SSH or RDP. Or you can enable ICMP for ONLY your ip if you really need to do so.